# get OpenGraph with PHP package fg/essence

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

hope this is not too specific:
I have a forum and I want my users to be able to paste links inside their posts, and show clickable images when published, getting the images from the link...something like facebook does when you paste a link in a new post.

I try to read multimedia data from a page with PHP package [fg/essence](https://github.com/felixgirault/essence), like the thumbnail, title, description, etc.

It works perfectly with specified providers, like youtube, vimeo, etc, but I have problems when it has to "degrade" to generic openGraph tags.
as an example, I cannot read data from [this](http://ed.ted.com/lessons/what-are-those-floaty-things-in-your-eye-michael-mauser) TED page, which contains OpenGraph tags.

I tried both version 2.x and 3.0 (under development), with the same result.
I also tried with package [euskadi31/opengraph](https://github.com/euskadi31/Opengraph) and I can read opengraph tags perfectly.

I cannot switch package because I don't want to rely on opengraph only, and Essence has an amazing method to replace links inside a text block which is perfect for this use but lacks in euskadi31/opengraph.

thank you

Comment: you are using this package https://github.com/felixgirault/essence ?

Comment: yes, exactly, the other one I mentioned is this: https://github.com/euskadi31/Opengraph